# Bootstrap4 menu-item stays selected and is only clickable one time

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, tabs, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm currently running into a problem with bootstrap 4 and a navigation which controls tabs. The menu itself looks fine but whenever you select another tab it will stay selected and you will be unable to select it again after moving to another section. This means after visiting all links you can't move anywhere. Not sure if I'm missing something or it's not meant to be used like that at all.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark py-0 mb-2">
  <!--APP NAV START-->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs mr-2" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <i class="material-icons md-light md-sm" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: white;">MENUE</i>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-info-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-info" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-info" aria-selected="false">Info</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" aria-selected="false" onclick="openExternal('http://jsfiddle.net/')">jsfiddle/</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-sub-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-sub" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-follower" aria-selected="false">sub</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-subsub-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-subsub" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-donations" aria-selected="false">subsub</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-subsubsub-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-subsubsub" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-subscriber" aria-selected="false">subsubsub</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-something-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-something" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-settings" aria-selected="false">something</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--APP NAV END-->
  <div class="ml w-75 dragable">
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Some Title</p>
  </div>
</nav>


<!--PARTIAL START-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-info" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-info-tab">INFO</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-sub" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-sub-tab">SUB</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-subsub" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-subsub-tab">SUB SUB</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-subsubsub" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-subsubsub-tab">SUB SUB SUB</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-something" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-something-tab">SOMETHING</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--PARTIAL END-->
```

Comment: shouldn't the common parent of the 'data-toggle="tab"' have 'nav-tabs nav' on it for tabs to work? But you seem to be using tabs at another level already; you are trying to achieve tabs inside tabs? You might need to override some bootstrap styles to achieve this;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override some bootstrap style definitions to achieve this.

- First add the classes 'nav' and 'nav-tabs' to the 'dropdown-menu'
- Then add the following css,

  ```
  .dropdown-menu {
    display : none !important;
  }

  .dropdown-menu.show {
   display : block !important;
  }
  ```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grrakesh4769/aq9Laaew/191335/